# searching for multiple keywords using getfiles

Tags: c#, getfiles, keyword-search

I'm using below code to look for files which carry any of these keywords. For now I could only look for `kword1` and if no files found, I start repeating the search for `kword2`. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to look for `kword1` *or* `kword2` in the same search. I've been looking on multiple sources and I cant seem to find the way.

Here is what I`ve done so far:

```
string[] matches = 
    Directory
   .GetFiles(
       path1, 
       "*" + kword1 + "*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of tricks you can do `using System.Linq`. First set up the test run like this:

```
var directoryToSearch = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

string
    kword1 = "exe",
    kword2 = "pdb";
```

The `Where` expression retrieves all the files, then filters them according to `kword1` and `kword2`.

```
var files = 
    Directory
    .GetFiles(
        directoryToSearch, 
        "*", 
        SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(filename=> filename.Contains(kword1) || filename.Contains(kword2));
```

The `Select` expression selects only the file name portion of the full path.

```
Console.WriteLine(
    string.Join(
        Environment.NewLine, 
        files.Select(file=>Path.GetFileName(file))));
```

---

[image]